# Is this part the glove box damper?

Tags: toyota, part-identification, avensis

While fully opening the glove box on my Avensis '02 (to get behind it for a job) I broke something. I did a bit of research and I can't be sure but it might be the glove compartment damper, which if it is I assume is not that important (to me anyway). I don't know for sure though. I was hoping if I described it maybe someone would confirm.

It's cylindrical and about the size of a fat pen and is screwed to the back of the glove box and then attached to the chassis with something like a string ... this string was very short and broke when the glove box opened fully.

Does anyone know for sure?

Also, if it's only to dampen the glove box (using weighting I'm assuming) then what is the purpose of the string?

Here's a photo ... you can see the broken "string" in the background. PS although it looks in the photo like it's connected to the hinge it isn't actually touching it at all.

[image]

Comment: A picture's worth a thousand keystrokes

Comment: I know ... The car is away at the moment though. I will try to get one later.

Comment: Is [this something like](http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/9/93/Glovebox_filter_1.JPG/670px-Glovebox_filter_1.JPG) what you are talking about?

Comment: @Paulster2 no that looks like a hinge to me, is it? My part is screwed to the back ( and to nothing else ) but is attached to the floor using what appears to be a piece of string.

Comment: I've got no clue then. This is the only "cylindrical" thing I can think of which would be attached to the glove box. Maybe the picture you are promising will help us in diagnosis.

Comment: @Zaid Added that photo ... btw sorry about all the typos and thanks for the edit I must have forgotten to check for mistakes before I posted.

Comment: @Paulster2 ... added that photo

Comment: What was it attached to? Also, does this actually prevent the glove box from closing or staying closed?

Comment: Is that a torch by any chance?

Comment: @Zaid Meant to mention that though the foreground end does give that impression from the photo due to the flash - no it's totally opaque plastic with no clear plastic for light to get through. Also it doesn't come out and it was attached to the chassis via that string.

Answer (score 1):

Going purely on the fact that it's a Toyota and that part looks very similar to one in the glove box of my Prius, yes, it's the damper. And I can confirm that the damper includes a spring, a couple of small wheels, and string.

The only downside to not replacing it is that opening the glove box becomes a fairly rough experience. I finally bought one when I noticed that the frame around the opening was getting fatigue marks on it.